# JavaScript outputs on second refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run a dynamic timer in java script, whenever i run its gives me nothing, but on second refresh it's giving the output running with the time that has been already started on first load. I'm considering here the local storage, cause i want to share the timer for multiple tabs. Any solution can help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var countDownDate=localStorage.getItem("time");

if(!countDownDate){
var today = new Date();
var fewhours=today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1);
localStorage.setItem("time", fewhours);
}
else{
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First run - you don't have record in Localstorage, so if is true, else is not working. Change logic for your script, im not sure what you want? script working same like you code write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so, let's take a look into the JS code here:

First, it tries to get the `time` from local storage.

```
if(!countDownDate){
  var today = new Date();
  var fewhours=today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1);
  localStorage.setItem("time", fewhours);
}
```

Then, if `time` was either not found or is equal to `false`, it will set it in the local storage. So far, so good!

```
else{...}
```

Okay. So, here is where things get tricky.

`if`/`else` blocks usually have the following functionality:

1. They check the statement inside the parentheses right after `if`.
2. If that statement is `true`, the code block (the code inside the curly braces `{}`) will execute.
3. If that statement is `false`, it will continue, ignoring any other `else` block that might come after it.
4. If right bellow the `if` block there's an `else`, it will move on evaluating that part. In any different case, it will continue executing the code normally

So what will actually happen in this case? If the code block corresponding to the `if` part of the code runs, meaning this is the first time we run it since there's no `time` in the local storage, JavaScript will ignore the code in the following `else {...}` block.

But we want it to run even the first time the page loads, don't we?!

If that is the case, we should consider moving the code that actually runs the countdown outside the `else` block. This way, our code will first check if `time` actually exists in local storage, and if not, it will initialize it. Then, it can move on with actually displaying the remaining time on the screen!

So, how do we fix this? Simple!

The only thing we have to do is remove the `else {` line, as well as it corresponding closing curly brace:

```
var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem("time");

if (!countDownDate) {
    var today = new Date();
    var fewhours = today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("time", fewhours);
}

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        // clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

But there is one final problem we will have to solve here:

[image]

If we run the page for the first time, `countDownDate` still does not hold the proper value for `time`, even though we just created it. This causes our update code to think the timer has expired. This can be solved by taking the value of `time` from storage one more time:

```
if (!countDownDate) {
    var today = new Date();
    var fewhours = today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("time", fewhours);
    // Get time one more time
    countDownDate = localStorage.getItem("time");
}
```

This way we immediately get the correct value and can move on with executing the rest of the code.

Bellow is the final version of the code, with all the changes described above:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        p {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem("time");

        if (!countDownDate) {
            var today = new Date();
            var fewhours = today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1);
            localStorage.setItem("time", fewhours);
            // Get time one more time
            countDownDate = localStorage.getItem("time");
        }

        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
                minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is over, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                // clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, thanks a lot for the great explanation. Understood, worked for me...

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you :)
Would you mind accepting the answer?